"Inverse" distribution of gaussian where variance depends on mean
Let's say I have a probability distribution, which is a gaussian where the variance depends on the mean
$ p(x|\mu)  = \dfrac{1}{2\pi a \mu} e^{-\dfrac{(x-\mu^2)}{2*(a\mu)^2}} $
a being a known constant.
How is then the distribution of the parameter $\mu$ distributed, given the observation of a sample x from that distribution? And how do I find it?
My first instinct was to use Bayes theorem, so $p(\mu|x)=\dfrac{p(x|\mu)p(\mu)}{p(x)}$, where $p(x|\mu)$ is the distribution above, $p(\mu)$ is a prior term, and p(x) can be computed as the integral of the numerator. But I can't seem to get sensible results, or maybe I'm doing this integral wrong.
Is my intuition correct on Bayes Theorem? How do I solve that integral to get a "good looking" distribution? Does this distribution have a name?

It depends entirely on what $p(\mu)$ is. If $p(\mu)$ is gaussian, then as you must know, you will get something nice. Otherwise, there is likely nothing you can hope for.
